# Experimental OS

Tags: operating-system

Can anybody suggest any experimental, easy to understand operating system written in a [high level language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language) on which I can do some interesting stuff as a learning experience.
There are some OS like [MikeOS](http://mikeos.berlios.de/), [TomOS](http://tomos.sourceforge.net/) etc but these are written in assembly languages.

Basically, I want an OS which has driver support for power management but should not be very large.

Comment: This question seems too vague.

Comment: Agreed. @Atishay try being more precise.  Words like "linux like", "small" and "high level language" all mean different things to different people.  Is C/++ high level to you? It isn't to me.  Is Haiku small?  L4?  And I already commented my guesses on "Linux like" but that's that hardest one of all to decode.

Comment: I think [high level language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language) is a pretty clear term to convey my meaning. And by small I meant a few thousand lines of code.

Comment: I have not seen an OS that is less than a few thousand lines of code that contains *power management*.  Further, "high level language" is not clear - C is a high level language for many purposes, and a lot of operating systems are written largely in C.  When you go higher, though, you have to design and develop garbage collectors, memory management, etc, and the languages don't provide those - lower level software does.  In fact, in many processors you have to use assembly to set up the stack for C, nevermind the MMU, interrupt controller, etc. So, no, your question is not very clear.

Comment: I believe your best bet is to start with a small OS such as minix, and delve into it.

Answer (score 3):

[House](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~kennyg/house/), written in Haskell ontop of the H interface and GHC runtime system.  Alternatively, consider a paravirtual machine that runs on Xen like mini-os (written in C, lives in the Xen repository) or [HaLVM](http://www.halvm.org) (a Haskell cross compiler to the Xen ABI).

Moving away from the Xen / Haskell realm, you could look at [Haiku](http://haiku-os.org/) - a reimplementation of BeOS in C++.

Comment: Can you suggest a Linux like OS

Comment: Define "Linux like".  Something written in C?  Xen and mini-os.  Something open source?  How about L4 Fiasco.  Something with over 6 million lines of code?  How about www.kernel.org...  Something POSIX compliant?  Sorry, all out of those ;-)

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't looked at the code myself, [MINIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINIX) has a reputation as an easy-to-understand educational operating system.  You'll have to see for yourself whether it has power management support, though the web size does say MINIX 3 is targeted at embedded systems, so I'd say your chances are good.